# Insert into...Select when not duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, exists

I've got a trigger which copies values from one table (OriginalTable) to another (ChangesDuplicate). This is working fine but how can I have it only apply if the `name` and `age` columns are different from that being inserted (with the same `some_id` value? Basically I want to ensure that only changed values of `name` and `age` are inserted per `some_id`. The code I've got below still inserts duplicates when triggered.

```
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO dbo.ChangesDuplicate ( 
                [some_id], 
                [name], 
                [age]
            )   SELECT
                [some_id], 
                [name], 
                [age]    
    FROM        dbo.OriginalTable    

    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT [some_id]
                FROM dbo.OriginalTable ot
                WHERE ot.[some_id] = [staff_id] AND
                      ot.[name] = [name] AND
                      ot.[age] = [age]
                )
    END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This is working fine but how can I have it only apply if the name and age columns are different from that being inserted (with the same some_id value? Basically I want to ensure that only changed values of name and age are inserted per some_id

You should use `Inserted` Virtual table which has access to newly inserted rows and do joins based on your Parameters.you are using Original Table twice in a trigger which doesnt have any value

The code below will insert rows into changedduplicate,if any new rows are inserted into Original table(assuming trigger is on this)  and matches with age and name of original table(you can add further conditions based on your need)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangesDuplicate ( 
                [some_id], 
                [name], 
                [age]
            )  
 SELECT
                [some_id], 
                [name], 
                [age]    
    FROM        dbo.OriginalTable  Ort  
                join
                inserted i
                on i.age<>Ort.name
                and i.name<>Ort.name
```

You could also use not Exists

```
 Insert into changesduplicate
    select * from inserted I 
    where not exists
    (select 1 from original o where o.name=i.name and o.age=i.age)
```

Comment: I must be missing something as neither answers work (nothing gets inserted). Could it be because some columns are varbinary?

Comment: The not exists code doesn't compile, `"incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'`

Answer (score 0):

Change `not exists` to `exists` with your conditions.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangesDuplicate ( 
            [some_id], 
            [name], 
            [age]
        )   SELECT
            [some_id], 
            [name], 
            [age]    
FROM        dbo.OriginalTable o   
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT [some_id]
              FROM dbo.ChangesDuplicate dt
              WHERE dt.[some_id] = o.[staff_id] AND
                    dt.[name] <> o.[name] AND
                    dt.[age] <> o.[age]
             )
```

Comment: I tried using this but nothing gets inserted in the ChangedDuplicate table at all. I have a lot more columns. Some are varbinary types, could this be a problem?

Comment: check the edited version to see if it makes a difference. i added a table-alias to the outer table.

Comment: No unfortunately nothing gets inserted. If I remove the `where` completely, all rows are copied across so the trigger is definitely being called.

Comment: i think the inner query should be for the changesduplicate table. modified the query again to reflect that. this should work

Comment: No insertions. If the code is correct, maybe I'm doing something wrong on my side. It matches the above 100% so not sure what it could be

Answer (score 0):

In the trigger you should 1) use `inserted` and/or `deleted` virtual tables.
The insert to `ChangesDuplicate` inside trigger looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangesDuplicate ( 
            [some_id], 
            [name], 
            [age]
        )   SELECT
            [some_id], 
            [name], 
            [age]    
FROM        inserted i
    left join dbo.ChangesDuplicate cd 
       on i.some_id=cd.some_id and i.name=cd.name and i.age=cd.age --full duplicate
where cd.some_id is null --doesn't exist
```

### Full working example:

```
create table OriginalTable (some_id int,name varchar(10),age int)
go
create table ChangesDuplicate(some_id int,name varchar(10),age int)
go
create trigger tr_orig 
   on OriginalTable  
   after insert,update
as
begin
set nocount on
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangesDuplicate ( 
            [some_id], 
            [name], 
            [age]
        )   SELECT
            i.[some_id], 
            i.[name], 
            i.[age]    
FROM        inserted i
    left join dbo.ChangesDuplicate cd 
       on i.some_id=cd.some_id and i.name=cd.name and i.age=cd.age --full duplicate
where cd.some_id is null --doesn't exist
end
go

insert OriginalTable values --all are inserted into OriginalTable 
(1,'test2',40), --inserted into ChangesDuplicate 
(2,'test2',40), --inserted into ChangesDuplicate 
(1,'test2',40) --not inserted into ChangesDuplicate
```

Comment: Nothing is inserted when I use this

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ChangesDuplicate ( 
            [some_id], 
            [name], 
            [age]
        )
SELECT
    [some_id], 
    [name], 
    [age]    
FROM dbo.OriginalTable ot
LEFT JOIN dbo.ChangesDuplicate cd
    ON cd.[some_id] = ot.[some_id]
    AND cd.[name] <> ot.[name]
    AND cd.[age] <> ot.[age]
```

Comment: @TryNCode I have updated my answer. Changed the table in left join from OriginalTable to ChangesDuplicate